# $\varphi^*: \operatorname{Spec} S^{-1}A \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is a homeomorphism onto a of $\operatorname{Spec} A$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $S$ be a multiplicative set of a commutative ring $A$ and let $\varphi:A \to S^{-1}A$ be the canonical homomorphism. Then $\varphi^*: \operatorname{Spec} S^{-1}A \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is a homeomorphism onto the subspace of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ consisting of prime ideals $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$ with $S \cap \mathfrak{p} = \emptyset$.

I'm trying to show the stated proposition and I have managed to get the following. $\varphi^*$ is injective as $\varphi^{*}(\mathfrak{p}) = \varphi^*(\mathfrak{q}) \implies \mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{q}$ and it's of course surjective onto it's image so I have two questions. Why do we have that $$\varphi^*\left(\operatorname{Spec} S^{-1}A \right) = \{ \varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}) \mid \mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec} S^{-1}A \} = \{\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec} A \mid  S \cap \mathfrak{p} = \emptyset \}$$ and why is it continuous with a continuous inverse with respect to the Zariski topology?

Answer (score 0):

On one hand, no prime ideal can contain an element of $S$, as by definition the whole ring can't be prime and $S$ becomes invertible on the localization.

On the other hand, for any prime $\mathfrak{p}$ in $A$ disjoint from $S$, consider the ideal generated by $\mathfrak{p}$ in $S^{-1}(A)$, which is the set of elements of the form

$$\sum \frac{r_i}{s_i} c_i \hspace{5mm} (s_i \in S, r_i \in A, c_i \in \mathfrak{p})$$

Now, if $ab = \sum \frac{r_i}{s_i} c_i$, then we just have (in $A$, and for some $s \in S$)

$$s \cdot \prod s_i \cdot ab = s \cdot r_i \cdot \prod_{j \neq i} s_j \cdot c_i$$

Since $S$ is multiplicative and $\mathfrak{p} \cap S = \emptyset$, we conclude $ab \in \mathfrak{p}$, hence our generated ideal is prime. Clearly the preimage of this ideal is $\mathfrak{p}$. This concludes the first question.

For your other question, note that the mapping $\varphi^\ast$ is **closed**: if $V(I)$ is a closed set, $\varphi^*{(V(I))} = V(\varphi^{-1}(I))$, as it is not hard to see that $\varphi^{-1}{(\mathfrak{p})} \supset \varphi^{-1}{(I)} \implies \mathfrak{p} \supset I$.

Thus, bijective + closed = homeomorphism.

Comment: Bijective + closed does not imply homeomorphism, you also need continuity